# How to create dynamic cron in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cron

I want to execute a cron after creation of some entity every 2 minutes and I should be able to stop it through code only. Is it possible ?

Comment: Have you looked at `whenever`? https://github.com/javan/whenever

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 1):

For the simplest way that I can think of right now that you can do what [@tlehman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29083152/4470982) said and add a "checking flag" in the code. (maybe just a simple variable inside a filename)

so before the cron started, it should check for a file with X variable with value true/false.

if true then it should run the code, if false then exit.

(you could then write another code to modify that "check file" to enable/disable the cron)

Comment: Thanks Firman. Can you please tell me how can i schedule a cron job in after_create filter of any model ??

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a job for the [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem, you can use it's simple DSL like so:

```
every 2.minutes do
  runner "SomeRubyCommand.do_work"
end
```

Comment: how can i schedule a cron after creation of an entity and how can i stop it ? I don't want the process to remain forever.

Comment: @firman-gautama has a solution, make the code depend on some flag, you could set the flag in your database.